# Prove that $\text{null} T_1 \subset \text{null} T_2$ if and only if there exists $S \in L(W,W)$ such that $T_2 = ST_1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Suppose $W$ is finite-dimensional and $T_1, T_2 \in  L(V,W)$.
>    Prove that
>   $\text{null} T_1 \subset \text{null} T_2$ if and only if there exists $S \in L(W,W)$ such that $T_2 = ST_1$.

If $\dim V<\infty $ then so is $\dim \text{null} T_1$ and then the problem becomes easy but here we have $\dim W<\infty $ .

How can we proceed here?Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Define $S$ on $\operatorname{im} T_1$ using $T_2 = ST_1$. Prove that this is well defined using $\operatorname{null} T_1 \subseteq \operatorname{null} T_2$. Extend $S$ to $W$ arbitrarily on a complement of $\operatorname{im} T_1$.

Comment: I need to show $T_2=ST_1$ .Then how can I use that

Comment: @Maths_Student, you force $T_2=ST_1$ to be true on $\operatorname{im} T_1$.

Comment: How to show that $S$ is well- defined?

Comment: @Hopmaths, ask a separate question describing your efforts and where you got stuck